# Javascript jest expect 0 equal -0

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I tried to create a jest test in ts, where the result should equal 0. This seems to fail on -0.

```
test("zero equals fails", () => {
  const actual = -0
  const expected = 0
//   expect(actual).toBe(expected)
//   expect(actual).toStrictEqual(expected)
//   expect(actual).toEqual(expected)
})
```

Gives:

```
Expected: 0
Received: -0
```

This even though the equals check in my console say they are equal.

```
0 == -0
true
0 === -0
true
```

What assert comparison should I use in this case?

Comment: Perhaps I'm too rusty with all of this but how is -0 a valid value? Wouldn't that just be 0 unless it were to be treated as something other than numeric?

Comment: @Elijah, it apparently has some uses. See [signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero)

Comment: @trincot Thanks for the education on this. I never knew of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of those methods use `Object.is` to compare primitive values, and `Object.is` fails when comparing `0` to `-0`.

There doesn't seem to be any [specific relevant method](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect) for this (there's `toBeCloseTo`, but that's not so appropriate, since the issue isn't floating-point precision).

A possible alternative is:

```
expect(actual === expected).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: I trust that you are correct in the Object.is usage; but I seem to read that toBe should use === ? ```/**
         * Checks that a value is what you expect. It uses `===` to check strict equality.
         * Don't use `toBe` with floating-point numbers.
         *
         * Optionally, you can provide a type for the expected value via a generic.
         * This is particuarly useful for ensuring expected objects have the right structure.
         */
        toBe<E = any>(expected: E): R;```

Comment: See the [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobevalue) on `.toBe`: *It calls Object.is to compare values, which is even better for testing than === strict equality operator.*

Comment: Should be fixed now: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/41250 It now shows that it uses Object.is, not `===`

Answer (score 1):

Jest is internally using [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) method to assert the value so it will be false.

```js
console.log(Object.is(0, -0))
```

Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

---

You can [extend and implement new method](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectextendmatchers) to use `===`(Strict Equality Comparison) or `==`(Abstract Equality Comparison) instead of [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is)( SameValue) method.

```
expect.extend({
  toBeEqCustom(received, expected) {
    if (received === expected) {
      return {
        message: () => `expected ${received} not to be ${expected}`,
        pass: true,
      };
    } else {
      return {
        message: () =>
          `expected ${received} to be ${expected}`,,
        pass: false,
      };
    }         
  },
});


// and use it like
expect(actual).toBeEqCustom(expected);
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers already talk about `Object.is`, which jest uses internally for comparisons. You could tweak your test to use `Math.abs` on -0.

```
expect(Math.abs(actual)).toBe(expected)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the consequence of how `Object.is` works. You could do as follows (assuming `expected` is not -0):

```
expect(actual === 0 ? 0 : actual).toBe(expected)
```